Query the lowest sub-value where the main value is grouped
I am trying to create a basis for a list of products in an MS Access Query. The basis must later be used in a form where the products are visualized with only one of the many images associated with each product.
The image name is calculated with an expression field based on the product ID and color ID, which is also the composite primary key for the table.
The table name: Images
Field Name  Datatype 
ProductID   Number
ColorID     Number
ImageName   Expression   [ProductID] & "-" & [ColorID] & ".jpg" 

A small output from the table with more than 62K records:



ProductID
ColorID
ImageName




100000
6
100000-6.jpg


100000
11
100000-11.jpg


100000
1546
100000-1546.jpg


100001
3
100001-3.jpg


100001
11
100001-11.jpg


100001
18
100001-18.jpg


100001
23
100001-23.jpg


100001
45
100001-45.jpg


100001
230
100001-230.jpg


100002
3
100002-3.jpg


100002
6
100002-6.jpg


100004
11
100004-11.jpg


100004
26
100004-26.jpg


100004
285
100004-285.jpg


100006
3
100006-3.jpg


100006
6
100006-6.jpg


100006
11
100006-11.jpg


100006
106
100006-106.jpg


100007
3
100007-3.jpg


100007
6
100007-6.jpg



I have tried using Distinct, and Group By with a MIN Min function with no success
SELECT ProductID, ColorID, ImageName
FROM Images
GROUP BY ProductID, ColorID, ImageName
HAVING (((ColorID)=(SELECT MIN(ColorID) FROM Images)));

What I expect from the query result:



ProductID
ColorID
ImageName




100000
6
100000-6.jpg


100001
3
100001-3.jpg


100002
3
100002-3.jpg


100004
11
100004-11.jpg


100006
3
100006-3.jpg


100007
3
100007-3.jpg




This question is similar to: MSAccess - query to return result set of earliest rows with a unique combination of 2 columns. If you believe it’s different, please edit the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.

Thank you, but it doesn't look like it was a solution in that link, and it was solved in a VBA that wasn't presented. But I tried the 2 suggestions, with no useful results.

Also, there is no unique combination of 2 values ​​I want in the result, except for the composite primary key.

1 value, 2 values, n values, concept would be same. And there was no VBA involved. But if answer resolves issue, congratulations. However, beware use of First and Last which can produce unexpected results because records do not have inherent order.

I hadn't realized the image filename was calculated from the two fields, so yes suggested link solution is not quite suited to your situation.

Try this:
SELECT A.ProductID , MIN(A.ColorID) AS ColorID , FIRST(A.ImageName) AS ImageName
FROM (SELECT ProductID FROM Images GROUP BY ProductID) AS B
INNER JOIN Images AS A 
    ON B.ProductID = A.ProductID
GROUP BY A.ProductID 

UPDATE:
As mentioned by June7, this code may return wrong results if the order ColorIDs are different as the sample data. Please see the correct answer by June7.

Wow, worked like a charm and 100% up to what I wanted.  Thanks a lot

Be wary of First and Last which can return unexpected results because records do not have inherent order.

@June7, you are absolutely correct. Thanks for the hint. Please let me know if it's better to delete the post or leave it as it is.

When I generated the ImageName name in the query, I could get the result I needed for now, but with the risk of course that the calculated image name in the Images table would change in the future. I should probably have used the result without the calculated value in a subquery, but good for now.
SELECT Images.ProductID, Min(Images.ColorID) AS MinOfColorID, [ProductID] & "-" & [ColorID] & ".jpg" AS ImageName
FROM Images
GROUP BY Images.ProductID, [ProductID] & "-" & [ColorID] & ".jpg"
ORDER BY Images.ProductID;


See the correct solution from Shahram Alemzadeh above mine.

Why do you consider calculating in query presents a risk? If you have Calculated field in table, it should reflect same result. If you are programmatically saving calculated result to a Text field, that is different issue - do not do that.

This turned out to be so much simpler than I expected. Consider:
SELECT ProductID, Min(ColorID) AS CID, ProductID & "-" & Min(ColorID) & ".jpg" AS ImageName 
FROM Images 
GROUP BY ProductID;

